# Strategies for managing legacy data for a medium sized enterprise

Tags: mysql, sql-server, legacy, oracle

I work for a mid market manufacturing company with around 1700 internal employees and about 7000 external users (employees of our customers).  We grew through acquisition which means we have many separate systems that serve that same function for different parts of our business (two ERPs, 3 CRMs, 3 e-commerce applications, dozens of BPM applications, dozens of various mobile apps, dozens of IoT devices, etc).

I am becoming increasingly worried about our data.  The product we manufacture has a 30 year product lifecycle and our customers expect us to have data from 1980 accessible at all times.  We probably have 50 million orders sitting in maybe 8 different systems on 8 different platforms.  We have credit data sitting in maybe 5 different systems on 5 different platforms, etc.  The orders/credits/etc all filter through to our ancient AS400 ERP but only the financial information, the rest is sitting in the system that gathered it.  Equally as concerning is that we have around 10 million technical design files scattered on various network drives with no type of heirarchy or query capabilities.

We have a data architect that is building a data warehouse for reporting but he is not keen on using that data warehouse as a "legacy lookup" that can be accessible to front line employees.

I'm wondering if anyone an share some strategies for managing this data. My main questions are.

1. What are the benefits and risks of leaving the legacy data  in it's current state then accregating through some type of SOA / BPEL system vs doing ETL and staging it in a central location
2. How often should current data be extracted (if at all) into a centralized DB?
3. Is it better to try and get this data into a uniform schema or to just keep it as it is and separate GUIs based on the schemas?
4. Are there ant COTs solutions that can assist?
5. Any tips / tricks for interfacing with a variety of different databases (DB2, SQL Server, Oracle 11g/12c, MySQL etc)?
6. Any networking tips/tricks to prevent the ETL processes from destroying our Network?
7. Should the storage and retrieval system of textual data be a different solution than file data?

I'm really just trying to figure out where to start here.

Comment: Your question, though I really like it, is probably way-too-broad for the Q&A format of this site. You may start by reading all about [Enterprise Application Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration) you can find.

Comment: .. found this [old SO question for book references about EAI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328062/any-good-eai-enterprise-application-integration-books).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it would be technically nice to have everything on a single modern system. Plus there would be several benefits, costs savings from retiring legacy systems, reduced data protection risks etc

However its a massive task to retire even a single system and here you have multiple interdependent systems from many acquisitions.

In my experience going for a compromise solution, where you interface the new system into the old, *is* lower risk, but doesn't realise the benefits, which are mostly gained from *not* having the old system, rather than having the data on the new system.

I would say the key things for a successful migration project are:

- Careful discovery process to map out all affected systems and processes
- A (long) change over period where both systems are in operation at the same time.
- Allow subsets of data to be migrated and start with a small set "test" customers
- Comprehensive testing of the migrated data. Checking against what the old system says.